Struggling to connect express backend to mongoDB due to IP address issue
i am building a Full stack ecommerce website for my brand . i can't connect to mongodb atlas with vs code although everything the code and URI strings is correct . the error indicates has a IP address issue.
I checked if any firewalls are blocking or DNS issue . tried to check Telnet but it is also just fine .
this is the error i got
Connecting to MongoDB URI: mongodb://rushikeshvadnal:######@cluster0.hejlr.mongodb.net/ecom
Server Running at http://localhost:7000
Error connecting to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\resoluteandrowe\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\resoluteandrowe\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:860:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    at async connectDb (file:///D:/resoluteandrowe/backend/Config/db.js:7:9) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'cluster0.hejlr.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}




import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import "dotenv/config.js"

export const connectDb = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("Connecting to MongoDB URI:", process.env.MONGO_URI);
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
            .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
            .catch((error) => console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}   


I was trying to connect to my mongoDB . I shared my string to my friend and he tried with the same string and it worked in his pc just fine . I tried with my mobile hotspot and also in another wifi connection but same error is shown . please help me out .
If anyone came across such a thing and can help me to find a solution .
thanks in advance for all the efforts and replies.
